# Cannot change name servers for domain

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I have two domains that refuse to accept changes to the name server records.  One domain has had this problem for 6 months and the other just did this today.  I use DreamHost as my domain registrar and I am trying to set Hurricane Electric as my name server.  When I go to set the name servers for these domains, I get no problems from the DreamHost panel, but even after days I am unable to detect any progress on setting the name servers.  It acts like the domain isn't registered when I query for records about it.  The two domains are colorpick.in and darkfission.net.  I set the name servers to ns2.he.net ns3.he.net ns4.he.net and ns5.he.net.  Could anyone give me any advice?

Comment: Talk with your registrar's support.

Comment: I have, and they just tell me to make sure the addresses are right for the name servers.  I also get a different person each response.

Comment: `darkfission.net` seems to be at HE, whereas `colorpick.in` does not seem to be registered.

Comment: Sheesh. GoDaddy does domains better than this. Next time you contact Dreamhost, demand that they have someone who knows what they're doing look at it.

Comment: If you are going to use another service, do yourself a favor: Move your domains to Gandi.net for registration. It seems you already have a new namserver, but I will also recommend Amazon’s Route 53 DNS service. Dirt cheap & works well.  I dumped Dreamhost 2 years ago & have never regretted it. Gandi is much better, much cheaper & more reliable.

Comment: This is definitely one where you need to talk to your registrar - we can't really tell you how to resolve this issue (aside from "change registrars") because it's not a *technical* problem, your registrar is just being sucky :-/

Answer (score 1):

The domain colorpick.in doesn't exist. Did you let it expire?

The domain darkfission.net has nameservers `ns2.he.net`, `ns3.he.net`, `ns4.he.net`, and `ns5.he.net` in the whois record. But the nameservers for `net.` aren't returning these NS records (as they should) or anything else about your domain.

This indicates that something is wrong with Dreamhost's process. When you update your nameservers with them, they are supposed to send this update to `*.gtld-servers.net`, the DNS servers which serve the `.net` top level domain. This doesn't appear to be happening.

If Dreamhost won't (or can't) fix it, transfer your domain to a registrar that has more competent staff.